How to monitor bandwith drops & connection losses?
My ISP currently seems to have a routing problem to certain servers/regions within my country whereas most of the connections generally are still fine. I can mainly notice this by extremely slow download speeds and/or unreliable connections to certain servers and my bandwith dropping to below 5% than my connection normally has if I hand-pick specific target servers in online connection speed tests. A very big problem is also that my employers VPN gets routed over one of the affected regions so once I'm within the VPN, I observe the same effect to any server I connect to.
How can I monitor, figure out and prove to my ISP that the issue is on their side? I've tried to analyse the situation with WindowsMTR and don't have in-depth networking knowledge but it seems to look fine for the most part.

This is a screenshot of the hops to one of the affected servers I currently only download with a few kb/s from. The only thing that stands out are hops 7 & 8 with a pretty high loss. But then, there are only 1/3 of all packets sent over these in the first place so is this normal/to be expected? MTR seems to be focussed on packet loss/latency and doesn't seem to capture the underlying issue well. How else can I do this?
